# Symfony2 : how to make a Regex in routing file for url argument in order to make clean url name

Tags: php, regex, symfony, url, routes

I would like to make a **regex** for a **route argument**, this my route file:

```
editBatiments:
    path:     /mypathto/edit/{name}
    defaults: { _controller: MyBundle:Mycontroller:editBatiments }
    requirements:
        name: // put the regex here
    methods: GET
```

This regex is for **delete** **space**, **underscore**, punctuation. But I want to **allow** uppercase and lowercase of course.In fact when i proceed the route, my url looks like this:

```
localhost/myFolder/mypathTo/edit/Name%20Of%20My%20BÃ¢timent
```

I would like to **delete** "%20" and space in order to have an url like **this**:

```
localhost/myFolder/mypathTo/edit/NameOfMyBâtiment
```

How can i proceed in order to have clean url?

I try this:

```
#route file
    editBatiments:
        path:     /mypathto/edit/{name}
        defaults: { _controller: MyBundle:Mycontroller:editBatiments }
        requirements:
            name: "[a-zA-Z0-9-_\/-\s.]+"
        methods: GET
```

But i have this error:

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template
>   ("Warning: preg_match(): Compilation failed: invalid range in
>   character class at offset 16 in
>   C:\wamp\www\MyFolder\app\cache\dev\classes.php line 848") in
>   MyBundle:MyFolder:indexBatiments.html.twig at line 60.

this is the code in `indexBatiments.html.twig at line 60` :

```
<td>
  <a href="{{ path('editBatiments', {'name': batiment.name}) }}">
    <button class="btn btn-warning btn-xs">Edit</button>
  </a>
</td>
```

Someone could help me in order to make a cean url when I proceed this route?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your regex to:

```
name: "[a-zA-Z0-9_\/\s.-]+"
```

i.e. keep **unescaped hyphen** as last character or first character in character class. Note that an unescaped hyphen in the middle of a character class is treated as range hence causing the exception you're getting.

PS: You can shorten your regex to:

```
name: "[\w\/\s.-]+"
```

---

**EDIT:** Looks like you're also matching unicode texts. Try this regex

```
name: "[\\p{L}\\p{N}/\\s.-]+"
```

Comment: @anabhava, I try your solution, but I have this error too: `An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Parameter "name" for route "editBatiments" must match "[a-zA-Z0-9-_/\s.-]+" ("BÃ¢timent A" given) to generate a corresponding URL.") in MyBundle:MyFolder:indexBatiments.html.twig at line 60.` In fact, when I click on Edit button, the route render a form where I can edit the Bâtiment I choose. And the url argument in my route is the name of this bâtiment I choose.

Comment: @french_dev, maybe you need to pass the requirement in line 60 in your indexBâtiment.html.twig?

Comment: If you're getting **must match `"[a-zA-Z0-9-_/\s.-]+"`** that means you're still not using my suggested regex above

Comment: Note that you still have an extra hyphen after `0-9`

Comment: @anubhava, I try but for now it does not work, I have the same error. I have the same error. I'm still searching for a solution. I add the regex in the requirements for the route.

Comment: @anubhava, The same error as I mentionned: `An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Parameter "name" for route "editBatiments" must match "[a-zA-Z0-9_/\s.-]+" ("BÃ¢timent A" given) to generate a corresponding URL.") in MyBundle:MyFolder:indexBatiments.html.twig at line 60.`. I try to remove the extra hyphen. Maybe I did not really understand what you suggested me. I have to create a better egex I think, no?

Comment: @anubhava, unfortunately I have the same error with your edit suggestion and the regex: `An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Parameter "name" for route "editBatiments" must match "[\p{L}\p{N}/\s.-]+" ("BÃ¢timent A" given) to generate a corresponding URL.") in MyBundle:MyFolder:indexBatiments.html.twig at line 60.` I'm still working on the regex. Maybe I have to add the regex in my twig?

Comment: Looks like you will have to add the regex to twig. I don't know much about that as I can only solve the stated problem. Original problem was **invalid range in character class** and looks like with my regex that has been taken care of.

Comment: @french_dev @anubhava is right. He solved your problem. You should post another question about how to make `slug` from any string with many not url-safe characters.